# Accidental space inserted - Why does this compile?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

I accidentally hit the spacebar and wrote this:

```
lTTEvent .CustUpdateStatus := usUnchanged;
```

and was surprised to see that the compiler accepted the space in front of the dot (actually, any number of spaces).

Is the dot such a special character that the parser can interpret it correctly? How would that work in Pascal?

Comment: You can insert linefeeds as well. And remove all the spaces around the `:=`. And add spaces before and after the `;`

Comment: Yup linefeeds are part of the whitespace family too.

Comment: You can also add comments, tab stops and other whitespace at any of these locations. Whitespace is only problematic inside keywords, identifiers and literals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The parser first translates text to tokens. So the text:

```
lTTEvent .CustUpdateStatus := usUnchanged;
```

Is translated to the tokens:

- identifier
- period
- identifier
- becomes
- identifier
- semicolon

The space is a whitespace and it can have three functions:

- separator between tokens (for example between an identifier and a keyword).
- a literal space (in that case it is included in a string.
- cosmetic.

The first and last function spaces are lost in the translation to tokens.

An identifier and a period don't have any characters in common so there is no way those can be confused so a space is not required but it still can be used.

**short answer**

'lTTEvent' and '.' are tokens. Tokens can (sometimes) be separated by whitespace.

Comment: I don't remember if this is the case in Delphi (I think so) but this is the same reason why `>=` cannot be written as `> =` (the former is one token, the latter are two.)

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, That's right. Because >= can be both '>=' and '>', '=', the whitespace is required. Else the compiler choses the largest matching token.